# Set Parent Item when using Migrate module

Tags: migrations

I'm migrating content from an old site using a CSV file. I have my own module setup that is importing all the other data using [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1006984).

Because this site is very large and has a very complex hierarchy, I'm hoping to set the Parent Item when migrating the content over. I don't see a destination for this type of data in the Migrate UI. Is there a way to do this?

I did see [this class](https://www.drupal.org/node/1560072) but it doesn't seem to be documented.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!